# Changing a Variable's name in a loop to avoid if

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

so I have following code that works with Arrays using If:

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim cont Integer
Dim B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 As Variant

cont = UBound(arr) + 1
If cont = 6 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
    B2 = Split(arr(1), ",")
    B3 = Split(arr(2), ",")
    B4 = Split(arr(3), ",")
    B5 = Split(arr(4), ",")
    B6 = Split(arr(5), ",")
ElseIf cont = 5 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
    B2 = Split(arr(1), ",")
    B3 = Split(arr(2), ",")
    B4 = Split(arr(3), ",")
    B5 = Split(arr(4), ",")
ElseIf cont = 4 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
    B2 = Split(arr(1), ",")
    B3 = Split(arr(2), ",")
    B4 = Split(arr(3), ",")
ElseIf cont = 3 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
    B2 = Split(arr(1), ",")
    B3 = Split(arr(2), ",")
ElseIf cont = 2 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
    B2 = Split(arr(1), ",")
ElseIf cont = 1 Then
    B1 = Split(arr(0), ",")
End If
```

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this with a loop and how it would look like. I came up with this but it did not work:

```
Dim arr as Variant
Dim i, cont as integer
Dim B(0 to 5) as Variant

cont = UBound(arr)
For i = 0 To cont
    B(i) = Split(arr(i), ",")
Next i
```

I get a `Sub or function  not defined` error message when trying to show B0(0). So you get an idea what I am trying to do this is a sample of the Array I am working with:`arr = split(string0, ";")` and `string0 = GEN /1,GEN /2;AT 1/1,AT 1/2;AT 2/1,AT 2/2;AT 3/1,AT 3/2;RES /1,RES /2;AT 4/1,AT`  .`B0(0)` should be then `"GEN /1"` and `B1(0) = "AT 1/1"`.  Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Variable names cannot be dynamically constructed. I have never seen a variable declared with `As Variable`. Code declares arr but don't see it populated. Show sample data.

Comment: As a very quick look over of the code, your `For` statement has `i=1...` meaning it will start at 1 whereas I think the ``Split` function creates a 0 based array. See if changing to `i=0` helps at all?

Comment: Tried your code and get "type mismatch" error on the `B(i)` line. Yes, Split is 0-based. Which means should be `cont = UBound(arr)` and `For i = 0 to cont`.

Comment: Unless module has `Option Base 1` and arr has been built as 1-based - which just confuses things. But again, AFAIK, variable names cannot be dynamically constructed.

Comment: What do you ultimately want to do with each arr element after it is parsed? There will never be more than 6 elements?

Comment: Made some changes to the code to match your suggestions. B0(0) shows "Sub or function not defined". And yes, there will never be more than 6 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The variable type is not varialble, but variant. You can use the redim statement to arrange the size of the array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, cont As Integer
    Dim B() As Variant
    
    'test array
    arr = Array("a,b,c", "d,e,f", "g,h,i")
    
    cont = UBound(arr) + 1
    
    ReDim B(1 To cont)
    
    For i = 1 To cont
        B(i) = Split(arr(i - 1), ",")
    Next i
    
    
End Sub
```